# Running linux shell command in background with '&' always fails

Tags: c#, shell, .net-core, process

I'm trying to run android emulator from dot net core. I'm using to do it this code:

```
    var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "/Users/hexdump/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb",
        Arguments = "-avd emulator-5444 &",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
    };

    var proc = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = psi
    };

    
        
    success = proc.Start();
    proc.WaitForExit();
```

Very standard code here. This works for all commands I run but this one that needs to be ran "dettached" doesn't work. Obviuosly it runs ok if executed from console.

As a sidenote, I have removed the "WaitForExit" call and somehow I have been able to do what I want. But, when I close dotnet the process I started is killed too (obvioulsy). And this is not what I want.

Is dot net core capable of running a script/executable in the background?

Comment: I haven't seen this issue in over 25 years.  Don't remember the solution.  Same thing happens in unix when spawning a shell.  I think it has to do with standard output.  When you are running from a command windows there is a temp location where standard output does.  You do not have a temp.  The environmental variables are empty in a c# Process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` is a shell construct. It says that you want to run the application in the background.

But you are not running a shell (such as `bash`). You are directly running a program: `/Users/hexdump/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb`.

To fix this, remove the argument `&` from the argument list. That makes .NET Core run the executable directly. You also need to remove the `proc.WaitForExit()` call, because you program doesn't want to wait for the emulator to exit.

---

The misleadingly named `UseShellExecute` has nothing to do with running in a Linux/macOS/Unix shell, it's the *Windows* shell. It behaves more like calling `open` (macOS) or `xdg-open` (Linux).