# Run a shell script from .Net Core application in Linux

Tags: c#, linux, shell, ubuntu, .net-core

I'm running a .Net Core app on Ubuntu 20.04, and I want to have a possibility to run a script (which runs some commands like git pull, stop my app service, run dotnet build, etc.) through a backend url, but the script that I need to invoke must be able to continue running even though my app service gets shut down through the script. I have tried many different ways but they all stop immediately the service is shut down!
The latest example is:

```
string scriptPath = "/path/to/script.sh";
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "bash",
    Arguments = scriptPath,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
};

Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);
process.Start();
await process.StandardInput.WriteLineAsync(scriptPath);
var output = await process.StandardOutput.ReadLineAsync();
exitCode = process.ExitCode;
```

Comment: When your c# application terminates all child processes are also terminated.  Also a process that is running will give an exception and terminate if there is no standard input or standard output.  In linux you can redirect standard output to null to prevent and exception.  See also : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread?view=net-7.0#foreground-and-background-threads

Comment: So, you are saying that there is no possible way to run a script that is independent from my application?

Comment: In bash you need the ampersand at end of line so code will run in background and continue running when you app terminates.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63958384/running-linux-shell-command-in-background-with-always-fails

Comment: I tried it's not working :( it still stops the execution of the script even if I put the ampersand:
string scriptPath = "/path/to/script.sh &";

Comment: Try CreateNonWindow = false to see if you see any clue to the issue.  Also Set Output and Error to False.  I assume the script works if you just run the script.  You may need Admin and if you are running inside VS you may need to start VS by right click VS shortcut and select Run As Admin.